# Проблема с ботом в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Бот в telegram отказывается работать, пробовал с 2 модулями

**telepot:**

```
import config
import telepot


basic_auth = ('tgfree_user', 'laip3Ez6')
SetProxy = telepot.api.set_proxy("http://140.82.37.240:10080", basic_auth)
bot = telepot.Bot(config.token)

bot.getMe()
```

**pytelegrambotapi:**

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def repeat_all_messages(message): # Название функции не играет никакой роли, в принципе
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Pkjhj")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=523)
```

Выдает ошибки

**pytelegrambotapi:**

```
    2018-07-12 13:33:41,391 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectTimeout occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot602759675:AAFMqMvRbFjzUQYIiMJbjwA0yQhJhuX7-sk/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=523 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0581DB50>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))",),) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa) socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 147, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.timeout)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0581DB50>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 281, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot602759675:AAFMqMvRbFjzUQYIiMJbjwA0yQhJhuX7-sk/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=523 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0581DB50>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 158, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 128, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 459, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot602759675:AAFMqMvRbFjzUQYIiMJbjwA0yQhJhuX7-sk/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=523 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0581DB50>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)')) " Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa) socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 147, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.timeout)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0581DB50>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 281, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot602759675:AAFMqMvRbFjzUQYIiMJbjwA0yQhJhuX7-sk/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=523 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0581DB50>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/kirit/Desktop/Бот/Telegram/bot.py", line 13, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=523)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 271, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 294, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 78, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 158, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 128, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 459, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot602759675:AAFMqMvRbFjzUQYIiMJbjwA0yQhJhuX7-sk/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=523 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0581DB50>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))
```

**telepot:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 324, in connect
    self._tunnel()   File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 914, in _tunnel
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()   File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line) http.client.BadStatusLine:  [      

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/kirit/Desktop/Бот/Telegram/bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    bot.getMe()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 503, in getMe
    return self._api_request('getMe')   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\telepot\api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 445, in urlopen
    return super(ProxyManager, self).urlopen(method, url, redirect=redirect, **kw)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 322, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 324, in connect
    self._tunnel()   File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 914, in _tunnel
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()   File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line) urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',))
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ошибки как текст (кнопка `править`)

Comment: у Вас похоже проблемы с интернетом, или провайдером, или вообще запещён доступ к телеграму... так как все ошибки ссылаются на не проблемы получения информации